# Is createApplication() method required for Laravel Dusk test cases?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I am attempting to set up Laravel Dusk in a Laravel 5.4 application. Executing `php artisan dusk` does not launch a browser window as shown in [this guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/introduction-to-laravel-dusk) and I am trying to figure out why. PHPStorm complains that the `ExampleTest` class created during execution of the `php artisan dusk:install` command must implement the `createApplication()` method, but I cannot find any mention of this method in:

1. [The official Laravel guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#installation)
2. [This Scotch.io guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/introduction-to-laravel-dusk)
3. A search of all files within the Laravel application directory using PHPStorm's search function.

ExampleTest class is as follows:

```
class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function ($browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                    ->assertSee('Laravel');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is required.

One method to solve this is to simply add the code contained in the trait (from a later version of Laravel) to your `DuskTestCase`.

```php
/**
 * Creates the application.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
 */
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    return $app;
}
```

Alternatively, you can create the `CreatesApplication` trait, paste the above code within in, and `use CreatesApplication` within your `DuskTestCase`.

Comment: That fixed the issue with PHPStorm, but I'm still not getting a browser window to appear when running 'php artisan dusk'. Could it be this issue here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987533/will-tty-mode-is-not-supported-on-windows-platform-error-prevent-tests-from-r

Comment: So, dusk usually runs in headless mode - meaning you won't see the browser do its thing as it runs your tests.

If you'd prefer to see what the browser is doing (i.e., take it out of headless mode) while the tests are running, you can add the `--browse` flag to `php artisan dusk`, like so:

`php artisan dusk --browse`